# My Python 3 file code is not appending nor reading right to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did a calculator code which works perfectly fine, but I need to append the results on a text file and/or read from the text file. I've done most of it but I'm having some errors which I need help with
-When I append the result, it just prints "5.098.042.0..." and it is supposed to be printing like this

"5 + 3 = 8

7 * 3 =43..."
  It does show it in the code, but for some reason it just prints the result in the text
Please help, any suggestions to save work in the future or anything will be appreciated, thanks!

```
    def menu():
            print("\t1. Addition")
            print("\t2. Substraction")
            print("\t3. Multiplication")
            print("\t4. Division")
            print("\t5. Show")
            print("\t6. Quit")


    def option(min, max, exi):
            option= -1

            menu() 
            option= int(input("\n\t-> What would you like to calculate?: ")) 
            while (option < min) or (option > max):
                    print("\n\t>>> Error. Invalid option.")
                    menu() 
                    option= int(input("\n\t-> What would you like to calculate?: ")) 

            return option


    def add():
            num1 = float(input("\tEnter a number: "))
            num2 = float(input("\tEnter a number: "))

            answer = num1 + num2
            print("\n\t-> The result of " + str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + "= ", answer)
            return answer


    def subs():
            num1 = float(input("\tEnter a number: "))
            num2 = float(input("\tEnter a number: "))

            answer = num1 - num2


            print("\n\t-> The result of " + str(num1) + " - " + str(num2) + "= ", answer)
            return answer


    def mult():
            num1 = float(input("\tFirst number: "))
            num2 = float(input("\tSecond number: "))

            answer = num1 * num2

            print("\n\t-> The result of " + str(num1) + " * " + str(num2) + "= ", answer)
            return answer

    def div():
            num1 = float(input("\tFirst number: "))
            num2 = float(input("\tSecond number: "))

            if num2 != 0:
                    answer = num1 / num2

                    print("\n\t-> The result of " + str(num1) + " / " + str(num2) + "= ", answer)
            else:
                    print("\n\t>>> Error. Division by zero.")
                    answer= "Error. Division by zero."

            return answer


    def result(r):  
            print("\n\t The last result was" , r)


    def ex():
            print("Goodbye")

    def main():
        solution = 0
        op= -1

        while op != 6:
                op = option(0, 6, 0)    
                if op == 1:
                        solution = str(add())
                        with open ("myResultt.txt","a") as f:
                            f.write(solution)

                elif op == 2:
                        solution = str(subs())
                        with open ("myResultt.txt","a") as f:
                            f.write(solution)       
                elif op == 3:
                        solution = str(mult())
                        with open ("myResultt.txt","a") as f:
                            f.write(solution)   
                elif op == 4:
                        solution = str(div())
                        with open ("myResultt.txt","a") as f:
                            f.write(solution)
                elif op == 5:
                        with open ("myResultt.txt","r") as f:
                            for line in f:
                                    print(line)
                else:
                    solution = ex()
                    with open ("myResultt.txt","r") as f:
                            f.close()

    main()
```

Comment: Are you asking why all the numbers are crammed together in a single line, instead of each one on its own line? If so: the `write` method writes only exactly the characters you give it; it doesn't try to do anything smart. So you can either add a `'\n'` to the end of what you `write`, or you can use `print` with an extra `file=f` argument if you want it to do the exact same thing to the file that it does to the screen.

Comment: Your functions prompt for the operands. If you want the operands in the file, the function will have to do that for you. You could just return the string you build for printing. Or write a terse string, use it to then print a verbose string and return that terse string for the file. Or even put the file write in the function.

Comment: As an aside, when you find yourself repeating code, there is usually a way to put it all into a simpler loop.

Comment: @abarnet could you show me how that would be written? It gives me syntax error

Comment: @tdelaney I've no clue about none of that you said, I'm on my first programming semester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You prompt for the operands in the `sum` and etc... functions. If you want those operands to appear in the result file, you either have to return them along with the answer, or do the write in the function itself. For example,

```
def add():
    num1 = float(input("\tEnter a number: "))
    num2 = float(input("\tEnter a number: "))

    answer = num1 + num2
    result = "{} + {} = {}".format(num1, num2, answer)
    print("\n\t-> The result of " + result)
    with open ("myResultt.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(result + "\n")
    return answer
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, I can't believe all I had to do was that, but it makes SO much sense now, again, thanks sir!!!!